# Смещение метки относительно балуна

Tags: yandex-maps-api, drupal, yandex-maps-jsapi, drupal7

У балуна настройки

```
 balloonPanelMaxMapArea: Infinity,
 hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
 balloonAutoPan: true,
```

При клике на метку,карта центрируется,из-за балуна метка располагается вплотную к балуну. Пытался добавить

```
balloonOffset:[]
```

но безрезультатно.
Пытался отключить balloonAutoPan и центрировать карту при клике на метку

```
myPlacemark.events.add('click', function (e) {
          var geoObject = e.get('target');
            myMap.panTo(geoObject.geometry.getCoordinates(), {
            delay: 0
          }); 
        });
```

Но не знаю как добавить смещение относительно центра

Comment: У меня метка по центру карты, которая не занята балуном-панелью https://jsfiddle.net/oc4e5kn7/ можете предоставить пример где метка появляется ближе к балуну?

Comment: пример не соберу,там балун собирается на drupal. У меня балун зафиксирован справа. за счет его ширины (400px),кажется что метка не по центруhttp://prntscr.com/knfini

Answer (score 1):

Карте можно добавить занятую область.

```
map.margin.addArea({top: 0, right: 0, width: '250px', height: '100%'})
```

Прочитать можно тут: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/map.margin.Manager-docpage/

Comment: Спасибо! Я копал в этом направлении,но не смещалось ничего. Попробую еще раз

Comment: Когда балун прижат к низу карты,то все ок. А когда справа,то не хочет отрабатывать

Comment: Пример есть, как у вас это реализовано? Можно разными способавми такую панель написать. Можно например так: https://jsfiddle.net/1cwpb0q7/

Comment: Я создавал новый пресет и у него прописывал
balloonPanelMaxMapArea: Infinity, balloonAutoPan: true,

Comment: в таком случае балун будет не сбоку а снизу. И выглядеть это будет так jsfiddle.net/oc4e5kn7

Comment: да,по умолчанию так,но я стилями зафиксировал его сбоку

Comment: Плохая реализация порождает проблемы. Если метка смещается через setCenter, то есть опция учитывать или нет margin https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#method_detail__setCenter-param-options.useMapMargin . При её использовании метка смещается куда-нибудь или остается в центре?

Comment: остается в центре

Comment: в таком случае добавление map.margin.addArea должно работать http://jsfiddle.net/0d37wp4f/

Comment: Вот сейчас отработало. Я без panTo пробовал в прошлый раз.Огромное спасибо.
Но сейчас такая проблема: первый клик отрабатывает как надо,но потом отступ пропадает. Я вывожу в консоль myMap.margin.getMargin(). И после первого клика выводится [0,0,0,0]

Comment: ну костылём будет добавление отступа перед кликом) Соберите минимальный пример воспроизводящий проблему, посмотрим почему так)

Comment: прочитал такой момент "Также в коде метода setArea есть проверка, что если поля сохраненного объекта и новой screenArea совпадают – то менять ее не надо.". Может из-за этого после первого клика больше не добавляет область

Comment: А когда открываю кластер,первый клик тоже отрабатывает правильно. Не подскажите,в чем проблема?

Comment: Соберите минимальный пример проблемы и я помогу разобраться.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sx1omfge/9/  не идеально,потому что многое генерирует смс,но вроде должно быть понятно. Посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: А что не так в этом примере http://jsfiddle.net/sx1omfge/9/ я нажимаю на метки и они сдвигаются вбок, а не остаются в центре. Как должно быть?

Comment: блин  просто не знаю как закинуть в пример. только при первом клике срабатывает отступ,а потом сбрасывается на [0,0,0,0]. Но когда закрываю балун,то все ок

Comment: Помочь без кода я вряд ли смогу. Попробуйте добавлять информацию так https://jsfiddle.net/1cwpb0q7/